# Bootstrap 3 long modal open fix postion

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I am working on mvc 5 application in that  I am using bootstrap modal(pop-up) when click on popup its open at proper position  showing image below [first time opening of modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xg2VY.png)

but when I click cancel button on  popup it close and  while re opening it change its position It causes scroll top of main screen how to avoid this showing in second image. .[Second time opening at wrong position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6L21Z.png)

Can anybody please provide me some inputs on this? it will be greatly appreciable.
thanks in advance

Comment: Can u post your button/link after click that it opens modal?

Comment: <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 pull-right margin10">
    <a href="#" class="create" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addUserPopup" id="CreateUserPopUp"> <i class="fa fa-plus"> </i> Create</a>
</div>

Comment: Remove the # from href="" and check once.

Comment: Not working  in my case

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#YourModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {   
    $(this).scrollTop(0);
});
```

Make scrollTop(0) it will work fine